# Electricity went out while installing software

Tags: cleanup

Just installed 14.04 so I gave the software centre about 5 programs to install and I left it and went away. Then the electricity went out.

What is the correct thing to do now?

Most importantly I want to clean up (remove) the "parts of softwares" that were installed.

...Is there something like a restore point to go back to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will fix and then continue the installation of any software which was interrupted when the power went out; although if the installation had not yet reached, say, the fourth program then you will need to manually install that and the fifth again.

There's no equivalent of a restore point to uninstall packages - you will have to do this manually if you don't want the software anymore.

If you get an error when running the above command then post it here and I will tell you how to resolve it.

Comment: okay so you mean that "the one software that was interrupted" will be "fixed" or "resumed" right?

Comment: ...anyway I ran the command and it gave the error `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` @Sman789

Comment: Run the command it tells you to run (without the quotes), and then run "sudo apt-get install -f" again.

Comment: And yes. The dpkg command will fix the package it was currently installing, and the apt-get command will make sure that all the other packages that are needed for it to work are present and installed. But there's no way for it to know what other, unrelated packages you wanted to install afterwards, so you'll have to start those again.

Comment: mmm okay thanks :D

...to be honest; I didn't wait for your reply and reinstalled my system but it really looks like it will work ... followed by Minos' answer down here to install the unrelated programs

Comment: For future reference: Minos' answer is equivalent to simply starting the installation again from the software centre, except it will needlessly reinstall programs which had already installed correctly as well. It also wouldn't work until you ran the above command anyway.

Comment: yes exactly! It's a step that _can_ be done after yours. no problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Unless something went terribly wrong I would just try reinstalling the programs:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall <packagenames here>
```

Comment: hmmm great! so where do I find the packages installed today?

Comment: what where you trying to install?

Comment: google chrome, VLC (which has apparently finished installation), gimp, wine, uuuuuuuuh and two more things (I'll say when I remember)

Comment: then try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable vlc gimp wine and whatever else you installed